# Adding Select2 data-option in Kartik Select2

Tags: php, yii2

Basically, I using [Kartik Select2](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#settings) to create a dropdownlist.

If I have a data like this :

```
<?php
$mapListNoEstimate = ArrayHelper::map($listNoEstimate, 'id', function ($model, $value) {
    return $model['no_surat'] . ' - ' . $model['level'];
});
```

In Select2 :

```
 echo $form->field($model, 'repair_estimate_id')->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'data' => $mapListNoEstimate,
    'theme' => Select2::THEME_CLASSIC,
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Select an estimate ...',
        'options' => [

        ]
    ],
])
```

, How can we adding some data-attribute ?

In my case, I want to add data-level in each option.

You know, in legacy select option, we can do like this :

```
<select>
    <option value='$model["id"]' data-level= '$model["level"]'> 
        $model['no_surat'] . ' - ' . $model['level']
    </option>
</select>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `options` within `options`. See the below sample.

```
echo Select2::widget([
'name' => 'kv-type-01',
'data' => [1 => "First", 2 => "Second", 3 => "Third", 4 => "Fourth", 5 => "Fifth"],
'options' => [
    'placeholder' => 'Select a type ...',
    'options' => [
        1 => ['data-level' => 'something 1'],
        2 => ['data-level' => 'something 2'],
        3 => ['data-level' => 'something 3'],
        4 => ['data-level' => 'something 4'],
        5 => ['data-level' => 'something 5'],
    ]
],
]);
```

Comment: Thanks body, but if I have 200 options, is it the way is recommended ?

Comment: You can create an array variable for it and pass.